# Shopify App Proxy with Submit Form won't submit correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, shopify

I tried to add multiple app proxy locations but despite seeming like it allows you to, the multiple links did not save to my application.  I currently have a form showing up fine but upon submit I am unsure how to handle it?  Submit with Ajax and render a message?  This is my controller as of now but it isn't hitting the create action at all upon submit.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :customer_authenticate

    def create
        product = Product.create(params[:product])
        if product.update_attribute(:shopify_id, product.set_up_product)
            flash[:notice] = 'Product was successfully submitted'
            redirect_to new_products_url
        else
            flash[:notice]= product.errors.full_messages
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end

    def new
      if params[:shop].present? && @store = Store.find_by_shopify_url(params['shop']) 
        render layout: false, content_type: 'application/liquid'
      else
        flash[:notice] = 'Application is not setup with store, please try again'
        redirect_to welcome_url
      end
  end

  private

  def customer_authenticate
    if params['shop']
        store = Store.find_by_shopify_url(params['shop']) 
    else
        store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
    end
    sess = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(store.shopify_url, store.access_token)
    ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(sess)
    session[:shopify] = sess
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the site is accessed via proxy the URL helpers didn't work so I had to specify the location like below in the form and it works well now.

```
<%= form_for(@product, url: ENV['HOME_URL'] + "/products", method: :post, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
```